# Laravel on IIS Hosting POST exceeds the maximum timeout of 300s

Tags: php, laravel, iis

I am trying to upload a working Laravel site onto IIS.
I believe everything is working correctly as I can see the landing page. But when I try to log in, the request keeps hanging until I get the error 'Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded'.

The Laravel debugger shows the following block of code.

```php
        try {
            return $this->createPdoConnection(
                **$dsn, $username, $password, $options <------ This line is red**
            );
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $this->tryAgainIfCausedByLostConnection(
                $e, $dsn, $username, $password, $options
            );
        }
```

So I presumed it was a problem with the Database connection, but when I connect to the database, for example by doing a User::All() on the landing page, it works perfectly.
Even in artisan tinker the connection seems to be established.

I have narrowed the place where the error establishes down, in the Laravel auth login.

```php
    protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
    {
        return $this->guard()->attempt(
            $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
        );
    }
```

I have no clue what's causing this, but I'm afraid it's an IIS error, although this seems unlikely given that the landing page works.

EDIT: It might be worth noting that when I transfer the site to XAMPP, the problem does not arise.

Comment: Do you have anything in storage/logs ?

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately it's more of the same.
```
[2019-09-24 14:51:33] local.ERROR: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException(code: 1): Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded at O:\\SPS\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\Connector.php:46)
[stacktrace]
#0 {main}
"} 
```

Comment: In my opinion, if you want to troubleshooting this issue, you should find out the where takes so long time. On the PHP site or the database. If you use sql server, I suggest you could try to use sql profile to check how long the database query the result.